# PHP: How I Can save the name of hyperlink in text box

Tags: php, mysql

Please help me in this code , I want to use instant search in php & mysql

if the user write the name in text box , then show all in data base value if the same

the value show by hyperlink the same as :

this page : result.php

```
$text = $_REQUEST['textx'];
  $text = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $text);
  $query = "SELECT * FROM employee WHERE name_emp LIKE '%$text%' AND  job_title='driver'";
  $action = mysql_query($query);
  $result = mysql_num_rows($action);
  if ($result == 0) {
    $output = "User does not exist...";
  }else{
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($action)) {
      $output .= '<div class="output"><a href="#" >'.$row['name_emp'].'</div><br />';

    }
  }
  echo $output;
```

if the user click on  one of the values this value appear in text box ,,
the text box exit in another page index.php .

how I can do it ??

index.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body {
    font: 100%/1.4 Verdana, Times New Roman, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #000;
}
/* ~~ Element/tag selectors ~~ */
ul, ol, dl { /* Due to variations between browsers, it's best practices to zero padding and margin on lists. For consistency, you can either specify the amounts you want here, or on the list items (LI, DT, DD) they contain. Remember that what you do here will cascade to the .nav list unless you write a more specific selector. */
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p {
    margin-top: 0;   /* removing the top margin gets around an issue where margins can escape from their containing block. The remaining bottom margin will hold it away from any elements that follow. */
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px; 
    border: none;
}
/* ~~ Styling for your site's links must remain in this order - including the group of selectors that create the hover effect. ~~ */
a:link {
    color: #42413C;
    text-decoration: underline; /* unless you style your links to look extremely unique, it's best to provide underlines for quick visual identification */
}
a:visited {
    color: #6E6C64;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
a:hover, a:active, a:focus { /* this group of selectors will give a keyboard navigator the same hover experience as the person using a mouse. */
    text-decoration: none;
}
/* ~~ This fixed width container surrounds all other blocks ~~ */
.container {
    width: 960px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    margin: 0 auto; /* the auto value on the sides, coupled with the width, centers the layout */
}
/* ~~ The header is not given a width. It will extend the full width of your layout. ~~ */
header {
    background-color: #bbe0f4;
}


*/
.sidebar1 {
    float: left;
    width: 180px;
    background-color: #EADCAE;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.content {
    padding: 10px 0;
    width: 600px;
    float: left;
aside {
    float: left;
    width: 180px;
    background-color: #EADCAE;
    padding: 10px 0;
}

/* ~~ This grouped selector gives the lists in the .content area space ~~ */
.content ul, .content ol {
    padding: 0 15px 15px 40px; 
}

/* ~~ The navigation list styles (can be removed if you choose to use a premade flyout menu like Spry) ~~ */
nav ul{
    list-style: none; /* this removes the list marker */
    border-top: 1px solid #666; /* this creates the top border for the links - all others are placed using a bottom border on the LI */
    margin-bottom: 15px; /* this creates the space between the navigation on the content below */
}
nav li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #666; /* this creates the button separation */
}
nav a, nav a:visited { /* grouping these selectors makes sure that your links retain their button look even after being visited */
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 15px;
    display: block; /* this gives the link block properties causing it to fill the whole LI containing it. This causes the entire area to react to a mouse click. */
    width: 160px;  /*this width makes the entire button clickable for IE6. If you don't need to support IE6, it can be removed. Calculate the proper width by subtracting the padding on this link from the width of your sidebar container. */
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #C6D580;
}
nav a:hover, nav a:active, nav a:focus { /* this changes the background and text color for both mouse and keyboard navigators */
    background-color: #ADB96E;
    color: #FFF;
}

/* ~~ The footer ~~ */
footer {
    padding: 10px 0;
    background-color: #bbe0f4;
    position: relative;/* this gives IE6 hasLayout to properly clear */
    clear: both; /* this clear property forces the .container to understand where the columns end and contain them */
}
/* ~~ Miscellaneous float/clear classes ~~ */
.fltrt {  /* this class can be used to float an element right in your page. The floated element must precede the element it should be next to on the page. */
    float: right;
    margin-left: 8px;
}
.fltlft { /* this class can be used to float an element left in your page. The floated element must precede the element it should be next to on the page. */
    float: left;
    margin-right: 8px;
}
.clearfloat { /* this class can be placed on a <br /> or empty block element as the final element following the last floated block (within the .container) if the footer is removed or taken out of the .container */
    clear:both;
    height:0;
    font-size: 1px;
    line-height: 0px;
}

/*HTML 5 support - Sets new HTML 5 tags to display:block so browsers know how to render the tags properly. */
header, section, footer, aside, article, figure {
    display: block;
}
-->
</style><!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"> 
function dtval(d,e) {
var pK = e ? e.which : window.event.keyCode;
if (pK == 8) {d.value = substr(0,d.value.length-1); return;}
var dt = d.value;
var da = dt.split('/');
for (var a = 0; a < da.length; a++) {if (da[a] != +da[a]) da[a] = da[a].substr(0,da[a].length-1);}
if (da[0] > 31) {da[1] = da[0].substr(da[0].length-1,1);da[0] = '0'+da[0].substr(0,da[0].length-1);}
if (da[1] > 12) {da[2] = da[1].substr(da[1].length-1,1);da[1] = '0'+da[1].substr(0,da[1].length-1);}
if (da[2] > 9999) da[1] = da[2].substr(0,da[2].length-1);
dt = da.join('/');
if (dt.length == 2 || dt.length == 5) dt += '/';
d.value = dt;
}
</script>
<script>



</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="search.js"></script> 

<script>
  function showHint(str) {
    if (str.length==0) {
      document.getElementById("inner").innerHTML="You haven't search.";
      return;
    }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
      // code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
        document.getElementById("inner").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
      }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("REQUEST","results.php?text="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
  }
  function setSelected(menuitem) {

    //JBP - get search result to place in search field on hover
    var title = $("#results ul li a").eq(menuitem).attr('title');
    $("#s").val(title);
    //

    $("#results ul li a").removeClass("search_hover");
    $("#results ul li a").eq(menuitem).addClass("search_hover");
    currentUrl = $("#results ul li a").eq(menuitem).attr("href");
}
</script>
<script>
  function showHint1(str) {
    if (str.length==0) {
      document.getElementById("inner1").innerHTML="You haven't search.";
      return;
    }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
      // code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
        document.getElementById("inner1").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
      }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("REQUEST","results1.php?textx="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
  }
  function setSelected(menuitem) {

    //JBP - get search result to place in search field on hover
    var title = $("#results ul li a").eq(menuitem).attr('title');
    $("#s").val(title);
    //

    $("#results ul li a").removeClass("search_hover");
    $("#results ul li a").eq(menuitem).addClass("search_hover");
    currentUrl = $("#results ul li a").eq(menuitem).attr("href");
}
</script>
<script>
  function showHint2(str) {
    if (str.length==0) {
      document.getElementById("inner2").innerHTML="You haven't search.";
      return;
    }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
      // code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
        document.getElementById("inner2").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
      }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("REQUEST","results2.php?textxx="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
  }
  function setSelected(menuitem) {

    //JBP - get search result to place in search field on hover
    var title = $("#results ul li a").eq(menuitem).attr('title');
    $("#s").val(title);
    //

    $("#results ul li a").removeClass("search_hover");
    $("#results ul li a").eq(menuitem).addClass("search_hover");
    currentUrl = $("#results ul li a").eq(menuitem).attr("href");
}
</script>
<script>
  function showHint3(str) {
    if (str.length==0) {
      document.getElementById("inner3").innerHTML="You haven't search.";
      return;
    }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
      // code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
        document.getElementById("inner3").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
      }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("REQUEST","results3.php?textxxx="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
  }
  function setSelected(menuitem) {

    //JBP - get search result to place in search field on hover
    var title = $("#results ul li a").eq(menuitem).attr('title');
    $("#s").val(title);
    //

    $("#results ul li a").removeClass("search_hover");
    $("#results ul li a").eq(menuitem).addClass("search_hover");
    currentUrl = $("#results ul li a").eq(menuitem).attr("href");
}
</script>
<script>
  function showHint4(str) {
    if (str.length==0) {
      document.getElementById("inner4").innerHTML="You haven't search.";
      return;
    }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
      // code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
        document.getElementById("inner4").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
      }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("REQUEST","results4.php?textxxxx="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
  }
  function setSelected(menuitem) {

    //JBP - get search result to place in search field on hover
    var title = $("#results ul li a").eq(menuitem).attr('title');
    $("#s").val(title);
    //

    $("#results ul li a").removeClass("search_hover");
    $("#results ul li a").eq(menuitem).addClass("search_hover");
    currentUrl = $("#results ul li a").eq(menuitem).attr("href");
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
 <?php
  $posted = false;
  if( $_POST ) {
    $posted = true;

$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$user_name="root"; // Mysql username 
$pass_word=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name="alkhaldi"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="trip"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$user_name", "$pass_word")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
 //List 2 
 $li=$_POST['textx'];
 $li1=$_POST['text'];
 $li2=$_POST['textxx'];
 $li3=$_POST['textxxx'];
 $li4=$_POST['textxxxx'];
 $num=$_POST['num'];
 $date11=$_POST['date1'];
 $date22=$_POST['date2'];
 $date_up=str_replace("/","-",$date11);
  $date_do=str_replace("/","-",$date22);
 $date1 =date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date_up));
 $date2 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date_do));
 $type=$_POST['type'];
 $r=$_POST['rec'];
 $d=$_POST['del'];
 $value="";
$allo ="";
 $diff= $r- $d;
$date_3= str_replace("/","-",$date11);
$day= date('d', strtotime($date_3)) ;
$date20=31-$day;
$date_2 = date('$date20 days', strtotime($date_3));
$date_1 = date('Y-m-d', mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m',strtotime($date_3)), date('d',strtotime($date_3)) + $date20, date('Y',strtotime($date_3))));
 $rs1 = "SELECT* FROM path WHERE path_num='$li4'";
 $rs = mysql_query($rs1);
 $name=$_REQUEST['name_emp'];

if($row=mysql_fetch_array($rs)){

$value=$row['value'];
$allo =$row['allo_trip'];

    }
     if ($li =="" or $li1=="" or $li2=="" or $li3=="" or $li4=="" or $num=="" or $type=="" or $date1=="" or $date2=="" or $r=="" or $d=="" or $diff=="" or $value=="" or $allo=="" )
 {

     echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Please enter all information ')</script>";
 }

         else

     {
        $sql="SELECT* FROM $tbl_name  WHERE num_dwn = '$num'";
        $result=mysql_query($sql);
        $anymatches=mysql_num_rows($result);
        if ($anymatches != 0)
    {
           echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Sorry , This information is exit , can not added agine ')</script>";
  exit;



    }
 else
 {
   $query = "INSERT INTO trip (name_emp,cus_num,car_num,truck_num,path_num,num_dwn,type,date_r,date_s,amount_r,amount_s,diff,value,allowance) VALUES ('$li','$li1','$li2','$li3','$li4','$num','$type','$date1','$date2','$r','$d','$diff','$value','$allo' )";
   mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

 }}

  $rs2 = "SELECT* FROM bill_trip WHERE date_1='$date_1' AND name='$li'";
   $rs5 = mysql_query($rs2);
$anymatches=mysql_num_rows($rs5);
 if ($anymatches == 0)
 {
   $query1 = "INSERT INTO bill_trip (name,Ttrip,Ttrip_allow,Ttotal_disel,date_1) VALUES ('$li','1','$allo','$value','$date_1' )";
   mysql_query($query1) or die(mysql_error()); 
 }
 else
 {
    if($row1=mysql_fetch_array($rs5)){

$total_trip=$row1['Ttrip'];
$trip_allow =$row1['Ttrip_allow'];
$disel=$row1['Ttotal_disel'];
$total_trip1=$total_trip +1;
$trip_allow1 =$trip_allow +$allo;
$disel1=$disel+$value;
    }
     $sql="UPDATE bill_trip SET Ttrip ='$total_trip1',Ttrip_allow='$trip_allow1',Ttotal_disel='$disel1'";
     mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()); 
 }}
 ?>
<div class="container">
  <header>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    </p>
    <p> Website for employee - Add new Trip</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
  </header>

  <div class="content">
    <section>
      <h5>Please enter the all information  </h5>
    </section>
<form id="search" name="search" method="post" action="" autocomplete="off"> 

    <table width="588" height="178">

 <tr>

 <td width="176" height="68" valign="top">

  <h5> Bill of Lading number *</h5>

 </td>

 <td width="295" valign="top">


     <input  type="text" name="num" maxlength="50" size="30">



 </td>

</tr>
<tr>

 <td width="176" height="68" valign="top">

  <h5> Customer Number *</h5>

 </td>

 <td width="295" valign="top">
<input id="text" type="text" name="text" onkeyup="showHint(this.value)"   value="<?php  if (isset($_REQUEST['cus_num'])  ){ echo $_REQUEST['cus_num'];}  ?>" />
<div id="inner" class="inner"></div>
 </td>

</tr> 
<tr>

 <td width="176" height="68" valign="top">

  <h5> Employee Name *</h5>

 </td>

 <td width="295" valign="top">

 <input id="textx" type="textx" name="textx" onkeyup="showHint1(this.value)" value="<?php  if (isset($_REQUEST['name_emp']) ){ echo $_REQUEST['name_emp'];}  ?>"  />

<div id="inner1" class="inner1"></div>


 </td>

</tr> 
<tr>

 <td width="176" height="68" valign="top">

  <h5> Car Number *</h5>

 </td>

 <td width="295" valign="top">
  <input id="textxx" type="textxx" name="textxx" onkeyup="showHint2(this.value)" autocomplete="off" />
<div id="inner2" class="inner2"></div>

 </td>
</tr> 
<tr>

 <td width="176" height="68" valign="top">

  <h5> Track Number *</h5>

 </td>

 <td width="295" valign="top">
   <input id="textxxx" type="textxxx" name="textxxx" onkeyup="showHint3(this.value)" autocomplete="off" />
<div id="inner3" class="inner3"></div>

</td>

</tr> 
<tr>

 <td width="176" height="68" valign="top">

  <h5> Date of Receipt *</h5>

 </td>

 <td width="295" valign="top">


     <input  type="text" name="date1" maxlength="50" size="30"  onkeyup="dtval(this,event);"/>



 </td>

</tr> 
<tr>

 <td width="176" height="68" valign="top">

  <h5> Date of Delivery *</h5>

 </td>

 <td width="295" valign="top">


     <input  type="text" name="date2" maxlength="50" size="30"  onkeyup="dtval(this,event);"/>

 </td>

</tr> 
<tr>

 <td width="176" height="68" valign="top">

  <h5> Cargo Type *</h5>

 </td>

 <td width="295" valign="top">


     <input  type="text" name="type" maxlength="50" size="30">



 </td>

</tr> 
<tr>

 <td width="176" height="68" valign="top">

  <h5> Quantity Received   *</h5>

 </td>

 <td width="295" valign="top">


     <input  type="text" name="rec" maxlength="50" size="30"/>



 </td>
</tr> 
<tr>

 <td width="176" height="68" valign="top">

  <h5> Quantity Delivered   *</h5>

 </td>

 <td width="295" valign="top">


     <input  type="text" name="del" maxlength="50" size="30"/>



 </td>

</tr> 


<tr>

 <td width="176" height="68" valign="top">

  <h5> Path Number   *</h5>

 </td>
 <td width="295" valign="top">
    <input id="textxxxx" type="textxxxx" name="textxxxx" onkeyup="showHint4(this.value)" autocomplete="off" />
<div id="inner4" class="inner4"></div>


 </td>

</tr>

  <td height="33" colspan="2" style="text-align:center">
    <p align="center">
      <input type="submit" value="Add new ">
      <input type="reset" value="Reset" />
      </p></td>



</tr>

<tr>

  <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">

      </td>

</tr>

</table>

   </form><br />
    <div align="center">
    <h5>  <a href="main_admin.php">back to home</a></h5>
    </div>

<!-- end .content --></div>
  <footer>
    <p></p>

  </footer>
  <!-- end .container --></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you ..

Comment: instead of $output .= '<div class="output"><a href="#">'.$row['name_emp'].'</div><br /> 

use 
 $output .= "<div class='output'><a href='#'>$row['name_emp']</div><br /> "

Comment: have you tried with jquery?

Comment: @amit_183 Rather than solving, that's only going to throw an error. @OP - Can you please be more clear on what you need? Do you need the value inside the `<a></a>` tags to be displayed on the text box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this....

```
<?php
$text = $_REQUEST['textx'];
  $text = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $text);
  $query = "SELECT * FROM employee WHERE name_emp LIKE '%$text%' AND  job_title='driver'";
  $action = mysql_query($query);
  $result = mysql_num_rows($action);
  if ($result == 0) {
    $output = "User does not exist...";
  }else{
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($action)) {
      $output .= '<div class="output"><a href="index.php?name_emp='.$row['name_emp'].'">'.$row['name_emp'].'</div><br />';
    }
  }
  echo $output;
?>
```

This below is for your index.php

```
 <?php
        //Index.php page,
        if(isset($_REQUEST['name_emp']) && $_REQUEST['name_emp'] != "")
        {
            echo "Name_EMP: "   .$_REQUEST['name_emp'];
        }

?>
```

Comment: @user3331228 problem solved or still finding solution?

Comment: Thank you very much , but the text box in another page for example in index.php ,, how I can do it ?

Comment: thank you the code is working but if open the page index.php  before choose the value this page appear mistake Notice: Undefined index .. but after choose the value the mistake is hide how I can hide the mistake before choosing ?? thank you for you

Comment: @user3331228 i have edited index.php code, replace with new one and try again.

Comment: Thank you ,, I have one problem only , I hope you help me the page index.php have more than one for this if i wane to choose another one the page refresh and the info is clear

Comment: can you write your index.php code in your question?

Comment: I write the code for index page ,, the index page have many of the text box of instant search ,, after choose the page refresh and clear another text box then  how I can solve this problem ? thank you ..

Comment: have you checked this  "if( isset($_POST) &&  !empty($_POST)) {" in place of this "if( $_POST ) {" at the top of the page.